# Comparing 2 Excel files using a primary key and merge the result

Tags: python

I have two Excel files , small example is as shown below

Sheet1

```
ID     AMT ORDER NAME
AB_1   10   2     A1
CD_2   20   5     A2
```

Sheet2

```
ID     AMT ORDER NAME
AB_1   30   3     A3
CD_2   40   4     A4
EF_3   50   5     A5
GH_4   60   6     A6
```

The common key here is "ID" , I need to compare the files  using the unique I'd: "ID"  I am trying to compare each of the columns in the above 2 Excel file.

Output

```
ID   AMT_1 AMT_2   ORDER_1   ORDER_2    NAME_1   NAME_2
AB_1 10    30       2         3         A1       A3
CD_2 20    40       5         4         A2       A4
EF_3       50                 5                  A5
GH_4       60                 6                  A6
```

How can I achieve this output?

```
ID   AMT_1 AMT_2   ORDER_1   ORDER_2    NAME_1   NAME_2

AB_1 10    30       2         3         A1       A3

CD_2 20    40       5         4         A2       A4

EF_3       50                 5                  A5

GH_4       60                 6                  A6
```

Comment: And the difference is just an additional newline?